# Copy files from one disk to other using local disk as staging

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, file-transfer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My question is about copying files off from an external disk to another with using local disk as staging.

I have my files on a USB disk (total size: 800 GB), which I need to copy to another USB disk (1 TB capacity.) While doing this, I have to use my local disk as staging - to say, I have to copy files first to local disk, and then to the other disk. The reason is that in the first USB, the files are encrypted. Copying files to the local disk decrypts the files.

I have to keep permissions and directory hierarchy as the files are backup files.

To make things more complicated, there is not enough space in my local disk - I can only use 50 GB of staging space.

I am very comfortable with Windows command line or Linux (Windows Subsystem for Linux.)

I prefer to solve this with commands or free applications. I am not looking for paid applications at this stage.

Thanks much for the help!

Cheers

Comment: Why do you assume that copying to the hard drive will decrypt them when copying direct to another drive won't?

Comment: I worked this with the encription application's support and this is what they told me.

Comment: Give more information about your setup and application.

Comment: I understand the desire to backup critical files.  What I don't understand is, the reason you would backup encrypted files, resulting in an unencrypted backup, both disks should be encrypted.  The reason being, of course, is by creating an unencrypted backup, you basically invalidate the entire reason the files are encrypted in the first place.  Having an unencrypted backup floating around is almost worst than the primary storage location not being encrypted.

Comment: The issue is not about whether the setup and the encryption of the backups. During the staging process the backups can be in an decrypted state, that's not a problem. After the files are removed from the current disk and decrypted, they will be copied to the new disk which also has encryption. My question basically comes how to do this: E:\Backup > C:\Staging_Dir > F:\Backups.

Comment: You should be able to do this via two instances of `RoboCopy` running at the same time.  I don't have the time to writeup an answer at the moment, but essentially the 1st instance will monitor _`C:\Staging_Dir`_ for `2` changes ( `/mon:2` - monitoring only 1 may result in a partial file copy), moving files to _`F:\Backups`_ from _`C:\Staging_Dir`_ via `/e /mov /z /eta /tee /log+:%userprofile%\unencrypted.log` also set.  The 2nd instance will copy _(**!! NOT `/mir` !!**) `E:\Backup`_ to _`C:\Staging_Dir`_ via `/e /z /eta /tee /log+:%userprofile%\encrypted.log` set

Comment: Thanks much @JW0914 I will give this a try.